SLURM maximum buffer size
In the slurmctld.log I have this error

error: Configured MaxJobCount may lead to job_state being larger then
maximum buffer size and not saved, based on the average job state
size(2.34 KiB) we can save state of 1790288 jobs.

In the slurm.conf I had changed to

MaxArraySize=100001 MaxJobCount=3000000 MinJobAge=2

I do not want to decrease the "MaxJobCount", but I suppose that I have to increase "maximum buffer size".
Could be related to innodb?

innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
innodb_log_file_size=64M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=900


or something else?
How can I increase the "maximum buffer size"? Thanks
PS. slurm-wlm 23.11.4

Hi Emma, how much RAM does your SLURM controller have ?

Hi tomgalpin, the Workstation where is installed the SLURM controller has 512G of RAM, but not sure how much is allowed to use SLURM itself to keep the system alive and avoid issues with the "max buffer size". According to the slurm.conf that workstation reserves "RealMemory=480000" for the jobs tha can run in it as node.
